# Software Update Implementation

Tags: c#

I am wondering how are software updates and patches implemented?

In my simple application written in C#, I have to rebuild the program if I have made any changes and then reinstall it again...

What are some good resources on this concept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following link to know about .NET Application Auto Update concepts.

http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at deploying it as a [ClickOnce application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=VS.100).aspx).

> ## ClickOnce Security and Deployment
>
> ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to **create self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run with minimal user interaction**. Visual Studio provides full support for publishing and updating applications deployed with ClickOnce technology if you have developed your projects with Visual Basic and Visual C#.

If you have a flick through the above and [Choosing a ClickOnce Deployment Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah.aspx) you will have a better idea of what ClickOnce can do and if it's suitable for your project.

If ClickOnce isn't suitable - it's great for small/medium projects, but not well suited to larger or offline deployments - you might consider using Windows Installer and it's [patching capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370578(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Sparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) can also be an option. And [Google Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/).

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this [book](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9780849358005) by CRCpress and this [software package by AgenSoft](http://www.agensoft.com/). Windows installer has provisions for creating patch packages also([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370578%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)).